# Printing out elements of List in Prolog

Tags: list, printing, prolog

I've got a list, X, that contains three elements; ID, Name, and Grade. All taken from user input

```
read_student_info([A, B, C]),
nl, nl, menu([[A, B, C] | X]).

read_student_info([A, B, C]) :-
  write('\tStudent ID: '),
  read(A),
  write('\tStudent Name: '),
  read(B),
  write('\tStudent Grade: '),
  read(C).
```

Now, I want to display the elements from the list. So if I have a student whose ID = 3, Name = Tom, Grade = 78. That's what I'd like to print out. The current function I've been fooling around with is this:

```
show_records(X) :-
  X = [A | B],
  A = [C | D],
  id = write(C),
  name = format("~s", [B]),
  grade = write(D),
  show_records(B).
```

However I'll be the first to admit I have almost no clue what I'm doing. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just suggesting a way to cleanup:

```
show_records([]).
show_records([A|B]) :-
  format('ID = ~w\tName = ~w\tGrade = ~w~n',A),
  show_records(B).
```

test:

```
?- show_records([[1,abel,10], [2,goofy,4]]).
ID = 1  Name = abel Grade = 10
ID = 2  Name = goofy    Grade = 4
```

clearly, tabs are not optimal, but simple to use

Answer (score 0):

I have it figured out, mostly anyway. Here is my revision.

```
show_records(X) :-
X = [A | B],
write('\tID = '),
A = [C | D],
write(C),
write('\tName = '),
D = [E | F],
format("~s", [E]),
write('\tGrade = '),
F = [G | H],
write(G),
nl,
show_records(B).
```

Comment: I suggest you use only once the explicit unification `=/2`: if instead of `X = [A | B]` you  write `X = [[C, E, G | _] | B]` and get rid of the other explicit unifications, your program becomes a lot more readable. And by the way, if your `H` is `[ ]`, that is the sublist has only 3 elements, then you should write  `X = [[C, E, G ] | B]`.